# Server method to return attribute not working properly Meteor JavaScript

Tags: javascript, meteor, client, server

I am trying to call a server method to return whether or not a hidden attribute exists. The attribute returns correctly in the terminal console, but does not return correctly on the client side (returns undefined). The attribute I want to return is `tireMarkup`.

Here is my method call:

```
var currentUserId = this._id;

    Meteor.call('checkMarkup', currentUserId, function(tireMarkupExists) {
        console.log(tireMarkupExists) //returns undefined
        if(!tireMarkupExists) {
            alert('Please enter a tire markup greater than 1 for the customer');
            alert(tireMarkupExists) //returns undefined
        }
```

Here is my server method:

```
Meteor.methods({
    'checkMarkup': function(currentUserId, tireMarkupExists) {
        console.log('user? ' + currentUserId); //returns the correct user
        a = Meteor.users.findOne(currentUserId); 
        console.log(a.tireMarkup); //returns the integer value correctly
        if (a.tireMarkup & a.tireMarkup > 1) {
            return (tireMarkupExists);
        }
      }
    });
```

Any thoughts? I think the problem has to do with the way I am passing the `currentUserId` and `tireMarkupExists` arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't return true/false values on the result, like this.

Change you server method to this.

```
Meteor.methods({
    'checkMarkup': function(currentUserId) {
        console.log('user? ' + currentUserId); //returns the correct user
        a = Meteor.users.findOne(currentUserId); 
        console.log(a.tireMarkup); //returns the integer value correctly
        if (a.tireMarkup & a.tireMarkup > 1) {
            return true;
        }else{
             return false;
        }
      }
    });
```

And use the `Meteor.call` like this.

```
Meteor.call('checkMarkup', currentUserId, function(error,result) {
        if(!error){
          if(result === true){
             console.log("tireMarkupExists");
          }else{
             cosnole.log("tireMarkupExists dont exist")
          }  
         }else{
            console.log("Opss an error : " error.reason)
         }
        }
```